# Android: Problem in showing MapView

Tags: android

I want to show Map on my android emulator. I have found one sample application HelloMaps in android API 7.
I have created API key and pasted that key in the `MapView` layout. Below is code for `mapview.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
     <com.google.android.maps.MapView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:apiKey="my_API_key_here"
             />
```

Following is code for in HelloGoogleMaps.java

```
 public class HelloGoogleMaps extends MapActivity
{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


}
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
{
    return false;
}
}
```

And following is manifest file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloGoogleMaps"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

With above code I am just able to see background area of Map but not actual Map.
Please help me If I am missing something.

Comment: Hi Please check [this link][1] more helpful to you [1]:http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android